# Mediaplayer сменить адрес ресурса

Tags: java, android

При попытке mediaPlayer.setDataSource() происходит вылет активити, если до этого адрес уже был установлен. Как правильно сменять адрес у mediaplayer

Comment: А Вы `reset()` перед этим вызываете?

Comment: Да вызвал reset(). Может это из за того что я установил дисплей поверхность. mp.setDisplay(surface)

Comment: А если выполнится reset(),  то дисплей заново надо будет устанавливать или нет?

Comment: Простите пожалуйста, не кидайтесь камнями... Оказывается мой метод, который достает из html кода(точнее js кода) url прихватил под конец еще и кавычку...